# Bootstrap4 beta. Footer hidden below Gmaps

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Not a global question but while I'm working with the beta of Bootstrap don't want to burn my brains before asking if it may be a bug or (most probably) I'm missing something.

I have a very clear & simple HTML structure ([link to it](http://www.4tres.com/esbadulake/)) with a main container split in 2 equal columns (50% width or 6 cols each) with a 100% width (fluid) + a footer that should appear below both (100% width) but it's hiddin under the Gmaps (iframe) not following what I consider the basic blocks (div) layout position.

I would appreciate anyone pointing out my mistake, if there's no other reasons.

Have a nice day!
hip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here. `#mainrow` has a position absolute. Remove that allows the footer to stack but the body has a `.d-flex` class that is forcing it to show next to the row. If you remove the absolute positioning from `#mainrow` and that `.d-flex` from `<body>` you should get what you are looking for (If I understood the question correctly)

Comment: Bingo! Despite it after following your suggestions I had to correct the container right-margin (to 0) to make the right column cover the whole (half) canvas. And yes, the new `Flexbox` utility in `Bootstrap4` has to be used with care, only in the appropriated places (not globally as I did). I'd live the static site at the same address for a while in case it may any interest.

Have a nice day.